# Two 3-Way Switches and One 4-Way Switch Controlling two lights. How do I convert the 4-way to a single pole switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Here is the situation.
At the top of the stairs I have two 3 way switches. (the left one controls the upstairs hall light and the office ceiling fan/light and the right one controls the ceiling stairs light)
At the bottom of the stairs is the other 3 way switch that controls the upstairs ceiling stairs light.

There is a switch next to the bedroom that controls the Hall/Office ceiling light/fan just as the switch next to the bathroom controls the Hall/Office ceiling light/fan (I will call this light switch 2)
What happens in this scenario is that, not matter what the Hall light is on, ALL THE TIME (very dumb), and we will call the switch next to the bathroom light switch 3.

What I want to do, is make the light switch 2, next to the bedroom to act as a single pole switch, independent of the others.

Here are some pictures.

We will call this light switch 1 because it holds two three way switches.
[image: light switch 1 location]

Here is the wiring for light switch one with the switch to the hall pulled out.
[image: Light switch 1 wiring]

Here is light switch 2 next to bedroom (I want this to act as a single pole switch).
[image: Light switch two location]

Here is the wiring for light switch 2.
[image: Light switch 2 wiring]

Here is light switch 3 next to the bathroom.
[image]

Here is the wiring for light switch 3.
[image: Switch 2 wiring]

Here is the situation above the stairs and "hall", which technically a hall but kind of. Stair light is present and I removed the hall light.
[image: Stair and Hall Lights (hall light removed)]

Top of stairs showing light switch one and two within 5' of each other.
[image]

Top of stairs showing light switch 3 within 5' of light switch 1 at the top of the stairs.
[image]

Here are light switch one close ups
[image: Switch 1a]
[image: Switch 1b]
[image: Switch 1c]

Here are light switch two close ups.
[image: Light Switch 2a]
[image: Light Switch 2b]

Here is light switch 3 close up.
[image: Light Switch 3]

Comment: Oops, you are correct.
I have updated.

Comment: FYI, light switch 2 is a 4-way switch, not a 3-way.  A "3-way" circuit has a 3-way switch at either end, with an unlimited number of 4-way switches in the middle.  Each switch in the chain "swaps" the wire carrying the power (between black and red), effectively inverting the state of the device that's being switched.  The input (or output) of the 3-way switches will be the screw labeled "COMMON"; the other two screws are for the carrier lines to the other switches in the chain.

Comment: I appreciate the education but I am looking for an answer if I can convert switch #2 to a single pole switch while leaving the rest as they are currently.

Comment: If the hall is the upper landing light for the stairs it is required to be controlled in the 2 locations upper and lower stairs.
The most probable answer is no modifying the circuit will affect everything. I believe that’s why @ereisch provided the detail. I am curious if this was a legal configuration to start with I see 2 grounds that would point to multiple runs of NMB. So it may be possible to make changes but we would need a full schematic of the lights and where they are fed from (we can really only see the wiring to the switches)

Comment: Light switch 1 is the upper light switch at the top of the stairs and at the bottom of the stairs is another three way, not shown in my pictures. The close ups provided show the three switches that all work together to control the Hall light above the bedroom door and the light/ceiling fan in the office. Again, the issue is that when any of those switches are turned on, the hall light is on. We would like to have the hall light switch 2 operate independently from light switch 1 and 3.

Comment: Is there a landing where light switch 2 is?

Comment: Just before the area where the top of the stairs comes to an end on the left is light switch 1 that can be used to turn the stair light, office light/fan and hall light on/off.
If you are referring to the area where the floor is flat after I took my last step up, as the landing, then there are two light switches, 2 & 3, that are actually within 5' feet of each other. See photos.

Comment: @ChristopherLond -- can you get us closeups of the wiring inside the light boxes? Also, how open are you to running new cables?

Comment: You want pictures of all the wiring from each box pulled out so you can see how they are twisted? I think I see where you are going with this. Yes, there is a closet in the bedroom where the light switch is on the outside wall so I could cut out a piece of drywall in the closet where the switch is and a piece near the ceiling where I could get access to the double header and drill a hole up and through to fish a 14/2 wire if I need to but I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that.
Its interesting that the wire at the light is a 14/2 but the wires at Switch 2 are 14/3

Comment: The wife says to remove the existing box, remove the light fixture, turn the existing box around where the open face is facing the inside of the closet and put a blank face cover on it. Now the ceiling is a different issue and I am not sure I can do this and that is to cap off all the wires and place the the wires in a junction box and leave up in the ceiling where I would then repair the hole with some drywall and mud. She says that light serves no purpose and to have that light on all the time when any of those three switches are in the on position is dumb

Comment: Update - Based on what I can tell, when I disconnect the 4-way switch none of the other switches work.
Question #1 Is there a way to terminate the loose wires in Light switch 2 so that Light switch 1 & 3 work?
Question #2 Can I alter the wires in Light switch 1 or 3 or both so I can do away with Light switch 2?
I have added close ups of the box wiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Splice the travelers through at switch 2 and slap a blank cover on that box, then cap off and cover the hall light box

Getting rid of the switch at position 2 is simple, fortunately: all you need to do is splice each traveler on one side of the switch (from switch 1) to its corresponding traveler on the other side (from switch 3).  In your case, this is especially easy because the prior installer did sane things with the limited colors they had, so simply splice red to red and black to black in that box, then slap a one-gang blank cover on it.

As to ridding yourself of the hall light, that's simple too.  Just cap off each wire that went to the fixture individually with a wirenut, and then put a round blank cover of the correct size on the box.  Now that ex-lighting-outlet won't irritate anyone by being on all the time.

Comment: Let me see if I've got this right. 
In switch box 2 splice red to red and black to black in that box and then put flip the box where it is in the closet and put a blank cover over it. Put the wires in a J box in the ceiling and repair the ceiling and closet drywall holes with drywall and mud.

Comment: Worked perfect! Just need to buy a half sheet of 5/8" drywall and I can repair the hole in both closets.